# rcleartool Atomicity

Tags: clearcase, atomic, clearcase-remote-client

Let's say I have a local view that gets periodically updated using **`rcleartool update`** from the central ClearCase server.  This update task takes 20~30 seconds to complete.

When my local view is getting updated during this 20~30 sec timeframe, what happens if:
**I checkout files that are going to be updated by `rcleartool update` ?**

Here I can only think of 3 situations:

- A. Update blocks, and thus checkout succeeds only after update finishes.  Things are good.
- B. Checkout happens before update, in which case either:

  - i) update will fail because files are checked out,
  - ii) update will succeed but put checked out files in hijacked mode, or
  - iii) Checked out files get updated successfully.  No hijacks.
- C. All sorts of race conditions happen and view explodes.

Which one would it be?

Also, what happens I do a checkin while update is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is: update should be on-demand, not automatic.

But should you keep that periodic automatic update, you could end up with one of the errors or defects mentioned in [this comprehensive CCRC list](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27009065).
Probably, you would have a "**[Version discordance detected for element when attempting a checkout](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21223087)**:

[image]
[image]

You have a [details in this technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21305088):

[image]

To [solve it with CCRC7.1](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_maintenance_discord.htm), you can refresh the file or the view, asking to repair said discordance.

[image]

Comment: Woops, totally missed your answer.  Thanks VonC (as always) for your quick replies, but unfortunately I don't have an option to use the UI to resolve version discordance.  Is there a programmatic way to do this?